# Why power operation on two identical matrix rows yields different values?

Tags: r

Example:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), nrow=2, byrow=T) 
> m ** c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,]    1 1.071773 1.551846 1.148698 1.620657
[2,]    1 1.231144 1.116123 1.148698 1.903654
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you under the assumption that things are getting applied rowwise

Comment: You're right, I just realized it's being applied columnwise. How can apply it rowwise?

Comment: I mean, is there a way to make the operation rowwise without `apply`?

Comment: Why not make the exponent a matrix of the same dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you mean this?

```
t(t(m) ^ c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4))
#[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,]    1 1.071773 1.116123 1.515717 1.903654
#[2,]    1 1.071773 1.116123 1.515717 1.903654
```

where `t(m)` returns the transpose of `matrix` `m`.

---

### Further explanation

You've fallen into the "recycling trap", where R automatically (and implicitly) recycles values to suitably match dimensions of vectors in a vectorised operation (here exponentiation). What you're doing is essentially the following

```
as.numeric(m)^c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4)
```

Written like this it becomes clear how R recycles the vector `c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4)` to match the length of vector `as.numeric(m)`. Recast as a `matrix` reproduces your original results.

```
matrix(as.numeric(m)^c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4), nrow = 2)
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,]    1 1.071773 1.551846 1.148698 1.620657
#[2,]    1 1.231144 1.116123 1.148698 1.903654
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), nrow=2, byrow=T) 
expnt <- c(.1, .1, .1, .3, .4)

# option 1
m ^ rbind(expnt, expnt)

# option 2
m ^ matrix(rep(expnt, each=2), nrow=2)

# more generalized (any number of rows) version of option 2 
nr <- nrow(m)
m ^ matrix(rep(expnt, each=nr), nrow=nr)
```